# I want to retrive data from a link which is loading continuously nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am unable to retrieve data from that link in Node js.

Comment: looks like link is loading continuously

Comment: Yes, when new data push into it it will show the data. like -

Comment: if its loading continuously, I don't think you need http call to get the data.

Comment: what is the solution? I also want to save that data in the database using Node js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a http request:

```
var http = require('https')


var options = {
  host: 'konnectprodstream3.knowlarity.com',
  port: 8200,
  path: '/update-stream/02a53c9aec84/konnect',
  method: 'GET'
}

const req = http.request(options, (response) => {
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log({ chunk: chunk.toString() })
  })

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log('End')
  })
})

req.end()
```

It will print:

> {
> chunk: 'id: 20\n' +
> 'data: {"event_type":"CUSTOMER_ANSWER","business_call_type":"Outbound","agent_number":"+919911782019","call_recording":null,"knowlarity_number":"+919311583261","uuid":"10e5bf5d-8e9f-465d-8920-3d0995210aae","call_direction":"Outbound","caller":"+919899625014","customer_number":"+919899625014","version":"1.0","k_number":"+919311583261","type":"CUSTOMER_ANSWER","unique_id":"f019cd36-37fb-43ab-afe3-0667c75584b1","call_solution":"c2c","FreeSWITCH_IPv4":"10.0.0.10","Other_Leg_Unique_ID":"10e5bf5d-8e9f-465d-8920-3d0995210aae_0","variable_current_application":"record_session","Event_Date_Local":"2020-08-13 18:12:21","variable_sip_call_id":"40404c79-5805-1239-a8b1-002590a61e05","Caller_Channel_Created_Time":"1597322532425716","Caller_Channel_Progress_Media_Time":"1597322533585716"}\n' +
> '\n'
> }

Since the format of the Server Sent Event is:

```
id: 20\n
data: <json>\n
\n # end of the message
```

You need to write a parser